# R data.table finding the mode for a group of data

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table x

```
id1 id2
a  x
a  x
a  y
b  z
```

For each combination of id1, id2 I can find the number of instances in the following way

```
x[,list(
    freq = .N
   ),by = "id1,id2"]
```

The above would yield

```
a x 2
a y 1
b z 1
```

Next I want to find the most frequent id2 for each id1, i.e. mode. So the expected result is

```
 a x 2
 b z 1
```

I can get there in a round about way, but is there a way to put a sequence number at the id1 level? Or some such hack that gets me to this efficiently and quickly, perhaps at the first step shown above?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
setkey(dt[, list(freq = .N), by=list(id1, id2)], 
         id1, freq)[J(unique(id1)), mult="last"]
   id1 id2 freq
1:   a   x    2
2:   b   z    1
```

The idea is to first get the `freq` column (as you did). Then `setkey` on the resulting `data.table` with columns `id1` and `freq`. This'll sort `freq` in ascending order already. With this, we can then do a `by-without-by` subsetting and combine it with `mult="last"` (because for every group, the last value will be the biggest, as it's sorted in ascending order).

This'll save a `sort` step for each grouping which can get time-consuming with increasing number of groups. Note that this does not handle ties. That is, if you've for same `id1` two equal max values, then only one will be returned.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. Curious, is the unique(id1) inside the J() call needed?

Comment: @broccoli, why don't you try it without `unique` and see what's the output :)?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `table`:

```
x[,{t=table(id2);r=which.max(t);list(names(t)[r],t[r])},by=id1]
```

which gives

```
   id1 V1 V2
1:   a  x  2
2:   b  y  1
```

You could plug names into that `list(...` part above to replace "V1" and "V2". And, of course, you can put the `{}` expression on multiple lines and get rid of the `;`'s if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 x[,list(
     freq = sort(table(id2),decreasing=TRUE)[1]
    ),by = "id1"]
   id1 freq
1:   a    2
2:   b    1

 x[,list(names_mode=names(sort(table(id2),decreasing=TRUE)[1]), 
     max_freq_id2 = sort(table(id2),decreasing=TRUE)[1]
    ),by = "id1"]
   id1 names_mode max_freq_id2
1:   a          x            2
2:   b          z            1
```

The usual caveats about finding modes applies here. This is only the first among many possible modes.